# Get the error text from strings.xml to model in MVP architecture

Tags: android, string, mvp

Model contains the logic of validating the input fields like email or password empty, email pattern error, or password length all these logic are in model and for every each validation different validation message to be shown.

So now if I directly access from R.java this model will not be reusable for other applications. So what is the good approach to follow in MVP pattern to show error messages.

Who should handle these error messages, model, or presenter? I'm unable to proceed further stuck with this one.

Comment: Well, you need to access `Context.getResources()` or `getString()` somehow. Would the Activity be the presenter? You can pass that error message into your model with a setter method

Answer (score 0):

The error message visualisation must be handled using View!

Your presenter have to call the related error method, for instance invalidEmail(), and the view have to decide how to interact with user and use UI elements to show the error.

In some implementations you may want to show an animation instead of a message! therefore sending the message from down layers to view is not right.

Comment: inavlidEmail() not only have one error message know it may contain like "Email id Empty", "Please enter valid Email (Email format)". So how view will identify which message to show. 

Or should i create 2 methods in view for corresponding error messages?

Comment: As you mentioned you have to think about different reaction that you may want to show. While there is limited errors that required to be handled you can manage them using different methods, but for a large project with huge number of errors you may want to have your errors Enum and pass it in a single method.